# Reading last printed line and delete it with a "if" statement

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am working on a TCP chatroom with python 2.7, my server should manage multiple clients (I used select module) and used threads for clients, I have a problem on what I am printing.
Since my raw_input in the client has text in it, it gets easily ugly when the other thread in charge of printing other clients messages gets triggered .

My code's results looks like this : (on client's window)

```
WELCOME TO CHATROOM
you are connected
your pseudo is PSEUDO
other_user joined the chatroom
```

and the my  raw_input() pops out and it goes like this :

`* < your message > * :e chatroom`

Or sometimes I get another user's message over Raw_input text

because it replaces the last line printed, I figured I could delete the last printed line if it's equal to my raw_input text to print an unexpected message over it and then reprint my Raw_input but I don't know to implement it.

I have tried moving my cursor with "\x1b["-like commands and deleting last printed line but those commands are not working for me.

```
class Sender(Thread):
    """would send messages to the server"""

    def __init__(self,  socket, username):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.socket = socket
        self.username = username

    def run(self):
        while 1:
            message = raw_input("* < your message > * :")
            self.socket.send(message)

class Receiver(Thread):
    import  sys

    def __init__(self,socket):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.connexion = socket 

    def run(self) :
        while 1:
            message_received = self.connexion.recv(4096)
            message_received = message_received.decode()
            sys.stdout.write("\r" + message_received)
            sys.stdout.flush()
            if message_recu =='' or message_recu.upper() == "OFF":
                break
        self._Thread__stop()
        print "\nClient arrete. Connexion interrompue."
        self.connexion.close()
```

Comment: Do you really need a message for your raw_input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For `\b` and `\r` to work you need to be ending your print statements with a space instead of a newline.

EG: 
`print 'hello there',` the `,` at the end of the `print` statement defines that it wont go forwards one line, but instead end it with a space. Then you can use another print statement to delete the text.

EG:
`print '\r '` this would go to the beginning of the line and replace it with a space, then you can output text over it.